# WPF Datagrid with dynamic columns, with different event listeners

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I am building an application using the MVVM pattern.

My problem is that my grid should have a dynamic amount of columns, that means it is not possible to simply bind a Collection to the itemsource.
Therefore I searched the web and found out that I can use a Dataview.
Now it is possible to create columns via the code, but I have the problem with different Events.

I need a listener if the user selects one or more cells. I need the start column/row and end column/row.

Further I want to show text if a user hovers over a cell (I think tooltips?) for every cell.
I get the content of every cell from the database. The content is a simple letter and a text which should appear when I hover over the cell.

Xaml:

```
 <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding DataView, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  SelectionUnit="Cell"  SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">



       
    </DataGrid>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    private DataView _dataView;
    public DataView DataView
    {
        get { return _dataView; }
        set
        {
            _dataView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataView");
        }
    }

 public MainWindowViewModel(IWindowController windowController) : base(windowController)
    {
        DataColumn colItem = new DataColumn("Arbeiter",
        Type.GetType("System.String"));
        ToolTip = " YAYA";
        DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
        table.Columns.Add(colItem);
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (long i = 0; i < (date -DateTime.Now).Days; i++) {
            colItem = new DataColumn(start.ToShortDateString(), Type.GetType("System.String"));
            start = start.AddDays(1);
            table.Columns.Add(colItem);
        }
      
       
        DataRow NewRow;
        DataColumn newCol;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            NewRow = table.NewRow();
            NewRow["Arbeiter"] = "TEST";
            table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
        // Change the values in the table.
        table.AcceptChanges();
        table.Rows[0]["Arbeiter"] = "FH";
        table.Rows[1]["Arbeiter"] = "WA";
        table.Rows[2]["Arbeiter"] = "FD";
       
        
        DataView view = new DataView(table);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the info about the selected cells try to use this:

```cs
private void On_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
    var grid = (DataGrid)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
}
```

The `grid.SelectedCells` will give you an `IList<DataGridCellInfo>` which is a list of those cells that you are currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a template for data grid cell and have an attach property by using interactivity support get handle of mouse hover event??

This might help you...

Comment: How to I creates such a template for a data grid? I am new to that.